# Wayland or Xorg for KDE Plasma on Gentoo new/clean install?

Tags: kde, gentoo, desktop-environment, wayland, plasma

I'm on a Gentoo clean/new install, and I'm wondering, for KDE Plasma Desktop Environment should I install Xorg or Wayland? My card is an AMD/ATI Radeon RX 550 LEXA PRO.

I'm looking for a performance, smooth and no issues/probs/bugs setup. I mean, I would like the desktop to be as much responsive as it could be where everything works as expected.

Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Stable KDE5 + Xorg. If you want to deal with a ton of bugs, you're welcome to use KDE6 + Wayland.

Comment: Remember you can do a little homework with `eselect profile list` to see which desktops are supported by pre-configured profiles.